# Не работает Postgres на Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Абсолютно не разбираюсь в Ubuntu. Запускаю сервер для ROR приложения с Postgres и получаю

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

К сожалению испробованных вариантов слишком много, что бы их перечислять. Есть ли какой то радикальный способ (кроме сноса самой системы - она к сожалению нужна) - что бы устранить проблему? Буду признателен за копипэйст варианты.

Comment: Это не "не работает", это "отсутствует ожидаемый unix socket". Скорее всего надо просто в настройках подключения указать сетевое подключение на localhost:5432, либо заставить постгрес слушать на unix socket, как описали в ответе.

Comment: К сожалению абсолютно не понял порядок действий.

Comment: а postgres установлен? сервис запускается? команда `ps -e | grep postgres` что покажет?

Comment: Поищите постгрес в выводе `netstat -ax`, увидите реальный сокет. Или не увидите, если у вас PostgreSQL не установлен вовсе. Когда я сталкивался с этим в последний раз, у меня в системе висели конфиги от старой версии постгреса, и поэтому новая версия взяла порт на единицу выше, приведя всех в замешательство.

Answer (score 1):

В файле `/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf` раскомментируйте строку

```
unix_socket_directory =/var/run/postgresql
```

Или добавьте, если нету.

Comment: Проверил - уже раскомментирована.

Comment: Директория `/var/run/postgresql/` есть? Прав у пользователя постгреса на запись хватает? После исправления конфига postgres перезапускали? Попробуйте симлинк сделать: `ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Comment: Компьютер -> /var/run/postgresql/ есть, но она пустая. А как проверить права пользователя на запись? Написал в терпинале эту строку с симлинком, выдает: ln: не удалось создать символьную ссылку «/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432»: Отказано в доступе

Comment: Для проверки права на папку выставьте `sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/run/postgresql`

Comment: Написал в терминале sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/run/postgresql  - ничего не происходит (терминал перезапускал - всеравно ничего).